# Wrong time in the Windows on dual-boot PC (Winwows/Linux)

Tags: linux, windows

On my PC I use two operation systems Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed that after booting Linux and then rebooting to Windows, Windows show the wrong time (Windows clock is 2 hours behind). 
I checked in the Linux - time is correct. 
I checked time settings - both OS have UTC+2 time zone and option to set time from the Internet.
If I correct time in Windows and do not boot Linux everything is O.K. But at list single loading Linux makes time shift.
I have tried to remove the option for setting time from the Internet. 
But manual time setting option changed nothing. What should be done to see the same time in the both operating systems?

Comment: Check what time is shown in bios. And what time difference you have in windows?

Comment: -2 hours: 6 insted of 8 in BIOS and Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set time zone UTC (London) in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

That's very popular problem.
All you need to do (and that's really the rightest way) is to say Windows that you hardware time is UTC.
To do it just add the following DWORD key to the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal
```

and set its value to 1.

Also you can youse QWORD key instead of DWORD if you have 64bit Windows. But, as far as I know, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and my solution is quite simple without changing any configs of your operating system.
Requirements: Need to have a internet connection for time sync. Have admin privileges.

**You need to enable windows time service**

1. Go to services by typing in the search bar.
   [Open services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPn6Q.png)
2. Search for windows time service (W32Time)
   [W32Time Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq5o4.png)
3. Change the Startup Type to Automatic
   [Change Startup type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OefDF.png)

**Creating a small bat script file**

1. Open Notepad and create a file with the following command.

   `w32tm /resync`
2. Save it anywhere with .bat extension. (Remember its location)

**Schedule a task**

1. Go to Task Scheduler by typing it in the search bar
   [Open Task Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXR13.png)
2. Right click on the empty space > create new task
   [Create New Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn5AF.png)
3. Give your task a name and description
4. Change "When running the task, use the following user account" to any admin user or admin group account.
5. Select "Run whether user is logged on or not"
6. Check the box for "Run with highest privileges"
7. Check the box for "Hidden" and "Configure for" = Windows 10
8. Go to Triggers tab, add the following triggers by clicking on "New..."

   - **First Trigger**

     - "Begin the task:" Select "At startup"
     - In Advanced settings, check the box for Enabled
   - **Second Trigger**

     - "Begin the task:" Select "At log on"
     - "Settings" Select "Any user"
     - In Advanced settings, check the box for Enabled
9. Go to Actions tab, create a new action by clicking on New...

   - "Action:" Select "Start a program"
   - In "Program/script" browse and select the file you created earlier.
   - And then click OK
10. Go to Conditions tab

    - Check the box "Start only if the following network connection is available"
    - Select your internet network or you can select "any connection" as wild card.
11. Go to Settings tab.

    - Check "Allow task to be run on demand"
    - Check "Run task as soon as possible ..."
    - Check "If the task fails, restart every" select "1 minute", "Attempts to restart up to:" 3 times
    - Check "Stop the task if runs longer than:" 3 Days
    - Check "If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop"
    - "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:"

      Select "Do not start a new instance"

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem recently. My solution is:

1. First make sure you have the correct time zone
2. Set BIOS time to local time.
3. In Linux, edit `/etc/default/rcS` by replacing `UTC=yes` with `UTC=no`.
4. Reboot.